# Azure Git: How not to select some files for merge

Tags: git, azure, merge, azure-devops, azure-repos

I am working with `Azure DevOps Git`. I have a repo with 2 branches **Development** and **Release**. I made 5 changes in **Release** branch, all in different folders, all in different commits. Now I need to merge only 3 of those changes to **Development** branch i.e. 2 of those changes should not be merged into **Development** branch. How can I do that?

In Azure web page, I went to my repo, click on *Pull requests* link to open it, then click on *New Pull request* button to start creating new Pull request. Then for source branch I select **Release** branch, and for target branch I select **Development** branch. Its Files tab shows 5 files. But I dont see any option to not select any of them.

Comment: Are those changes in a single commit or as different commits?

Comment: @PranavSingh they are in different commits

Comment: try cherry pick https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Can you explain the role of the two files that you want to exclude ? Do you know that you will *never ever* want those changes in your `Development` branch ? or do you want to exclude them now, but will need them in the future ?

Comment: @LeGEC I will never ever want those changes in Development branch

Comment: Agree with LeGEC, since you ever ever want these changes in `Development`, we could revert those two specific changes. You can also revert it in the Azure devops UI instead of git command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never ever want these changes in `Development`, you can revert those two specific changes, and merge that in `Development` :

in your local repo :

- from the `Release` branch
- create a new branch (choose a name, I will call it `wip`)
- on this branch, revert the two commits you want to skip :

  ```
   git revert <hash of commit1>
   git revert <hash of commit2>
  ```
- push this branch to devops :

  ```
   git push -u origin wip
  ```

on DevOps :

- create a new Merge Request, asking to merge `wip` into `Development`

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Pranav Singh would be the best option, cherry-picking.  When you create a PR you are merging one branch into another.  If you are only wanting to merge part of the changes I would make a new branch based off the default branch and then cherry-pick the changes into that new branch.  You do not want to cherry-pick from one branch into the default branch as that defeats the purpose of a PR.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick
The raw git manual is a great resource but sometimes hard to read through.

Sometimes it is easier to read here
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick

I would say also then make sure to merge or rebase the default branch into the original branch (where you cherry-picked from) once you complete the PR.  This way if it causes any Merge conflicts you can address them sooner than later.